# Why get back this error message when I subscribe in DolphinDB java api

Tags: java, dolphindb

I have a table in dolphindb:

```
t = streamTable(30000:0,`id`time`sym`qty`price[INT,TIME,SYMBOL,INT,DOUBLE])
share t as Trades
```

And I want to subscribe this table in java client.

```java
PollingClient client = new PollingClient(8892);
TopicPoller poller1 = client.subscribe("localhost", 8848, "Trades");
```

But it has errors as following：

[image]

Comment: most likely your 8892 is already occupied by some other process. have you tried with a different port or freeing up this port before running this above code?